# Get x and y in quadrat equations system

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

I need help in solving following system of quadratic equations :

$$
2x^2+y^2=4$$
$$2xy-2x=-5$$

I used every known me equations solving methods, but no was helpful for me... Can you help me by giving step-by-step solution (that is homework and I really need it...) ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no real solutions.  The resultant of $2 x^2 + y^2 - 4$ and $2 x y-2 x+5$ with respect to $x$ is $4\,{y}^{4}-8\,{y}^{3}-12\,{y}^{2}+32\,y+34$, which has no real roots.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

From the second equation we have, $2x(y-1)=-5,x=\frac{5}{2(1-y)}$

Put the $x$ in the first

Comment: Good idea ! But what with y ?

Comment: Substitute what the answer hints you in the first equation, get the value of $\;y\;$ and *then* substitute this value in either of the equations and get the $\;x\;$ value.

Comment: @DonAntonio I need step by step solution - I cannot make experiments

Comment: @Ty221, I seriously doubt you'll get one in this site. You see, we're assuming you *already know* something about this stuff and  thus that you're not expecting us to do **all** the work for you, so hints more or less explicit is the best you can expect in general.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, I am new here - in FAQ there is information  that I will receive answer - not a hint

Comment: FAQ? What FAQ? I thought they, for some reason I can't understand, deleted that section time ago....Anyway, it is not like that, @Ty221 . Sorry...thought there may be someone wanting to do that for you, who knows...

Comment: I meant "about" section, @DonAntonio ... http://math.stackexchange.com/about

Comment: You're right, @Ty221 : there it is. Yet I think you'll find most  member of this particular site don't agree with that. I know I don't, anyway.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, thanks for hints - now I am writing solutions